# how can i rewrite or derive a decimal representation into a diophantine equation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers, perfect-powers

How can i convert the form  \begin{equation}
\label{eq:(3)} {\overline{a \ldots ab \ldots b}}_{(10)} = y^2,
\end{equation} (Suppose that $ 1 \leq a \leq 9$ and
$0\leq b \leq 9$ are two integers, not necessarily equal)

into this diophantine equation?

$$
10^{m}\cdot a \frac{10^{n} - 1}{9} +b\cdot\frac{10^m-1}{9}= y^2 ,
$$

Comment: Without the digit $b$?

Comment: yes sir mr.piquito, i really have a hard time comprehending this research topic which is given to me, i do a lot of advance study just to understand this so that i can explain this paper work but i still have difficulty in this, i understand already the form aaabaaa(thanks to your help) but i cant understand this new form  even if i already tried the same way that you did in converting aaabaaa.can you help me please?I am asked to understand all the 4 theorems so that i can make my own which is the 5th one...your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry but the paper says $$
10^{m} \cdot a \frac{10^{n} - 1}{9} = y^2 ,
$$... it is mistakenly edited by peter but still thanks to him

Comment: I just noticed my error and edited it again.

Comment: The digit $a$ is the same in both equations? The integers $m$ and $n$ are given or not?

Comment: Well thanks anyway Peter. These things happen

Comment: Suppose that $ 1 \leq a \leq 9$ and
$0\leq b \leq 9$ are two integers, not necessarily equal, such
that
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:(3)} {\overline{aa \ldots ab \ldots b}}_{(10)} = y^2,
\end{equation}
where the number of $a$'s in equation (\ref{eq:(3)}) is $n$ and
the number of $b$'s is $m$.

Comment: I am really confused with this theorem so i really need to find for a help(thanks peter and piquito) i do the same thing in aaabaaa for but i failed in solving the theorem 4 in[perfect powers with all equal digits but one][1]    [1]:https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL8/Kihel/kihel7.pdf

Comment: i dont know if that is exactly the corrct form, i am also skeptical if there is an error in typography in theorem 1 when it says $10^$ln$$ but the proof says that $m$ is a multiple of $l$, so it should be $lm$ and not $ln$

Comment: i think it can be written in the form aaaabbbb if b=o so it is $aaaa0000$ the aaaa is the multiplicand of 10^m and the $oooo$ is the $10^m$, i just need confirmation about my work, if i did it right? im starting to think if there is typography in this paper because of the theorem 1 which says 10^ln but the proof says m is a multiple of l so it should be 10^lm

Comment: so the theorem 4 is (for the application) just for numbers 100,1000 so and so forth? so how does it become \noindent $\bullet$ If $m = 3$, then equation (\ref{eq:(3)})
yields
$$
10^3 aa \ldots a + 111b = y^2.
$$ ?

Comment: i also want to ask for clarification if it does not have any typo when it says 10^ln instead of 10^lm in theprem 1 and 4\

Comment: @Mr.Curious The expression I mention in the current version of the question gives $n$ $a's$ followed by $m$ $b's$. If $b=0$, this converts into the expression given in the paper.

Comment: @Peter, thank you sir,

Comment: the solutions of $a$ are 1,4 and 9 .Does it mean that we can generate perfect powers in the form aaaa0000=y^2 but there are only finite of them meaning there are many of them but just countable? they except 1*10^ln ,4*10^ln and 9*10^ln because these numbers can generate many solutions infinitely (or so many which is no longer countable) is that what theorem 3 means(similar with theorem 1)?

Comment: Hi @Peter,@Piquito  i just want to ask if What does it mean by this statement?it is in the same journal but i cant understand this

Obl\'ath  proved that the only perfect powers all of
whose digits are equal to a fixed one $ a \neq 1$ in decimal
representation are 4, 8 and 9. This is equivalent to saying that
the diophantine equation

 $a\frac{x^{n}-1}{x - 1} = y^{q}, \; \mbox{in
integers}\;~ n\geq 3,~ x \geq 2,~ 1 \leq a \leq x,~y \geq 2,~ q
\geq 2
$
has no solution when $x = 10$ and $a \neq 1$.

Comment: I can always read that statement whenever i search for something which is related to perfect powers, can someone elaborate that please, because i havent seen the work of oblath yet because it is not available whenever i browse the internet.

i  cant think of any number which is a perfect power but has all the same digits when we let $x=10$ and $a=1$

Comment: or it just means that  $a$ must be equal to one and $x$ can be any number so
it now means that it must be 4,8 and 9  because these are the only perfect powers that result from ($x=3,n=2)$ ,$(x=7,n=2)$ and $(x=8,n=2)$  when $a=1$ and $x$  can be any number but these are just one digit number but how come it states that all of whose digits are equal where in fact there is just one.Or is it just me who has a wrong interpretation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose there are $M$ digits in the period 
$$\overline{aa \ldots abb \ldots b}_{(10)}=0.aa\ldots abb\ldots b\space\space  aa\ldots abb\ldots b\space \space aa\ldots abb\ldots b.......\\\overline{aa \ldots ab \ldots b}_{(10)}={aa \ldots abb \ldots b}\left(\frac{1}{10^{M}}+\frac{1}{10^{2M}}+\ldots\right)=\frac{aa \ldots abb \ldots b}{10^{M}}\left(1+\frac{1}{10^{M}}+\frac{1}{10^{2M}}\ldots \right)=\frac{aa \ldots abb \ldots b}{10^{M}}\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{10^{M}}}\right)\\\frac{aa \ldots abb \ldots b}{10^{M}}\left(\frac{10^{M}}{10^{M}-1}\right)=\frac{(aa \ldots a)10^m+bb \ldots b}{99\ldots9}$$

Can you follow to finish? (*notice here there are $m$ digits $b$*)